# What do I add to my IAM policy to grant permission for tag processing of API Gateway resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I built a SAM template to deploy a `AWS::Serverless::Api` resource. While I did not specify any tags I get the following error: `Did not have IAM permissions to process tags on AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi resource`. I'm using a policy that follows the least privileged best practice. I'm curious what I can add to my IAM policy so that this error does not appear in the CloudFormation output. The resource is getting created I just would like to eliminate this error.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem as well. It's confusing because every other service seems to have its own tagging permissions. For example: `dynamodb:TagResource`

The ApiGateway documentation does not have good information on this, and the error message they display is vague.

To solve this, I created a user and attached the same policy I was using for my automation. When I tried to add a tag to my ApiGateway API, I received this error message:

```
User: arn:aws:iam... is not authorized to perform apigateway:PUT on resource arn:aws:apigateway.../tags/...
```

Using this information I added something similar to this to my policy:

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "apigateway:PUT"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/tags*"
    ]
}
```

The error in my CloudFormation stack then went away. If you haven't solved this already, I hope the answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the `tag:TagResources` permission. Also include the resources necessary to update or delete these tags, otherwise, you will run into permission issues when updating or deleting resources in your stack.

You can find all the `tag` permissions on [the cloudonaut page](https://iam.cloudonaut.io/reference/tag.html).